# How to use a different port for confluent-kafka?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I have a Kafka running in a port different to the default 9092.

How can I tell confluent-kafka to use that port? Because neither in the [API documentation](http://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html) nor [Github](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python) I see a "port" configuration, just the bootstrap server config, which is only to define the IP of the Kafka endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap server parameter doesn't define only the IP. It's a list of Kafka endpoint defined as : separated by comma. So for example in your case if you have Kafka on a non standard port i.e. 9093 and on localhost the bootstrap server parameter can be localhost:9093.

Answer (score 0):

You could see this https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md

it says the bootstrap.servers is alias for metadata.broker.list

And the metadata.broker.list description is :

> Initial list of brokers as a CSV list of broker host or host:port. The application may also use rd_kafka_brokers_add() to add brokers during runtime. 
>   Type: string

Actully you could use this

```
{'bootstrap.server' : 'ip:your_host,...',
 ....
}
```

as Kwargs to producer or consumer initiation.